# Updating UI with invoke or a background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im working on a school project where I need to do some temperature measurements. The task is to randomly create some temperatures and then calculate the average. My code is as following, but I have a problem with the Threads. It can't be called a object before a window handle is created. I searched the net and found out that a background worker is more useful for updating the UI. I'm not that skilled in programming yet, because i just started school.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Temperatur
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        static ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();
        static SemaphoreSlim w, e, b;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            w = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            e = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
            b = new SemaphoreSlim(6);

            Thread t1 = new Thread(randomNr);
            t1.Start();

            Thread t2 = new Thread(gennemsnit);
            t2.Start();
        }

        public void randomNr()
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //b.Wait();
                //w.Wait();
                int number = rnd.Next(36, 42);
                tempList.Add(number);

                listBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(number);
                });
                //w.Release();
                //e.Release();
            }
        }

        public void gennemsnit()
        {
            double avg = 0;
            double nb = 0;
            //Thread.Sleep(200);

            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++) //i < tempList.Count
            {
                //e.Wait();
                //w.Wait();
                nb += Convert.ToDouble(tempList[i]);
                avg = nb / tempList.Count;

                listBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate //listbox2.invoke
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(avg);
                });
                //w.Release();
                //b.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It can't be called a object before a window handle is created.

Don't start the threads in the constructor of the Form.  Use either the Load() or Shown() events instead:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        w = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        e = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        b = new SemaphoreSlim(6);

        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(randomNr);
        t1.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(gennemsnit);
        t2.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine now with the invoke and load.
But i still want to try that background worker though.

Comment: Same thing applies, though, don't start the BackgroundWorker() from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker is indeed what you need. If you "report progress" you can pass an object to the GUI thread in the progress report. Set up progress reporting like this:

```
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
```

...

```
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
```

...

```
        void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here you have passed yourself any object you like. Could be your own class. Could be a string, etc.
    MyClass myObject = e.UserState as MyClass;


    // Then you can add it to your GUI as necessary, for example
    listbox2.Items.Add(myObject);    
}
```

You probably just want to pass a string as your object and then add that string to your listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, but your task is quite easy. You don't really have to worry about threads. For simplicity you could schedule a timer to run every say 1s and pick a random number / read temperature and update it on the UI. If you select the timer from the forms controls (System.Windows.Forms.Timer) then you can directly update the UI from the function it calls when it fires. If you use a timer from System.Timers.Timer, you should use BeginInvoke to update the list.

Comment: Forgot to say that in the task you need to include threads to control it. But thanks for answering anyway!